# Custom StackLayout inflates more objects than it supposed to

Tags: android

I have a custom FrameLayout viewgroup that has "addCard()" method, which adds another custom FrameLayout child into it called TinderCardView.

Here is the function -

```
public void addCard(TinderCardView tinderCardView) {
    if (onCardSwipedListener == null)
      onCardSwipedListener = tinderCardView.getOnCardSwipedListener();

    topCardOnStack = tinderCardView;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int childCount = getChildCount();
    addView(tinderCardView, 0, layoutParams);

    float scaleValue = 1 - (childCount / 50.0f);

    tinderCardView.animate()
        .x(0)
        .y(childCount * yMultiplier)
        .scaleX(scaleValue)
        .setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator())
        .setDuration(DURATION);
  }
```

The issue starts when I need to instantiate a new card, which needs an interface that determines what happend when a card is being swapped -

```
  public TinderCardView(Context context, OnCardSwipedListener onCardSwipedListener) {
    super(context);
    this.onCardSwipedListener = onCardSwipedListener;
    init(context, null);
  }

public interface OnCardSwipedListener {

  void send(Object object);
  void onNext(Integer integer);

}
```

So, inside my MainActivity I try to set a new stack layout and it creates way more subviews then it should -

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    observeLiveData();

    initViewsAndListeners();
  }

  private void initViewsAndListeners() {
    tinderStackLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tinder_stack_layout);
    mDeleteButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_delete_button);
    mPassButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_pass_button);
    mApproveButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_approve_button);
    mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mApproveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPassButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    listener = new OnCardSwipedListener() {
      @Override
      public void send(Object object) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Integer integer) {


        if (integer == 1) {
          addCards(1);
        }

      }
    };
  }

private void observeLiveData() {
    userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, users -> {
      //update a new list of users
      usersList = (ArrayList) users;
      addCards(-1);
    });
  }

  private void addCards(int stackSizeToAdd) {
    TinderCardView tinderCardView;

    for (int i = index; index < i + (STACK_SIZE + stackSizeToAdd); index++) {
      if (index >= usersList.size()) {
        index = 0;
        i = 0;
        addCards(-1);
      }
      tinderCardView = new TinderCardView(this, listener);
      tinderCardView.bind(usersList.get(index));
      tinderStackLayout.addCard(tinderCardView);
    }
  }
```

I am for sure doing something wrong with my loop but I can't figure out what.

my variables at start -

```
private static final int STACK_SIZE = 2;

  private TinderStackLayout tinderStackLayout;
  private OnCardSwipedListener listener;
  private UserViewModel userViewModel;
  private ArrayList<User> usersList;
  private int index = 0;
```

So my issue actually is getting one more card than needed. The first card when starting the application is being duplicated, so this is why I though I am not getting the right stack size. but when swipping and deleting some cards, there is no more duplication. So my issue is understanding why the first card is being duplicated.

Comment: where is the definition of ```index```?
what do you expect ```addCard(-1)``` to do?

Comment: index is 1. 

addCard(-1) should keep the size of the stack the same as it is without incrementing the size of the stack.

Comment: it wont, look at my breakdown
just swap index for 1 in the breakdown table, and see how many iterations you get
i chose an arbitrary stack size constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int i = index; index < i + (STACK_SIZE + stackSizeToAdd); index++) {
```

suppose index is 0 at start, and you do `addCard(-1)`

index is 0, stackSizeToAdd = -1, STACK_SIZE = 10

first iteration

```
| i | index | index < i + (STACK_SIZE + stackSizeToAdd)| 
------------------------------------------------------
  0     0       0< 0 + (10-1)   
  0     1       1 < 0 + (10-1)
  0     2       2 < 0 + (10-1)
  0     3       3 < 0 + (10-1)
    ....
  0     9       9 < 0 + (10-1) => STOP
```

**this iteration will run 9 more times**

if index was 1 at start

```
   | i | index | index < i + (STACK_SIZE + stackSizeToAdd)| 
    ------------------------------------------------------
      1     1       1 < 1 + (10-1)
      1     2       2 < 1 + (10-1)
      1     3       3 < 1 + (10-1)
        ....
      1     10     10 < 1 + (10-1) => STOP
```

index = 1, stackSizeToAdd = -1, STACK_SIZE = 4

```
    | i | index | index < i + (STACK_SIZE + stackSizeToAdd)| 
    ------------------------------------------------------
      1     1       1 < 1 + (4-1)
      1     2       2 < 1 + (4-1)
      1     3       3 < 1 + (4-1)
      1     4       4 < 1 + (4-1) => STOP
```

Comment: tried that with index 0 and stack size of 2 and got always 4 cards inside my stack, shoudn't I get 2 cards?

Comment: how many cards are you expecting to get ? please notice ```i``` is only assigned once

Comment: do you delete the previously added cards ? this loop will always add 3 cards, regardless what was there before

Comment: also need to take into consideration that you change ```index``` and ```i``` in case index surpassed the size of the users list

Comment: 3 users at start, the first one is being duplicated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200498/discussion-between-lena-bru-and-alon-shlider).